# IIS Url Rewrite doesn't work with Firefox and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, redirect

I have the below rewrite block in my web.config

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It redirects all request to https when browsed pages through IE. When I access the pages in Chrome or Firefox, they don't seem to be redirecting but stay on http only.  I can't see https in the address bar except for IE.  Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: This isn't `ASP.NET Redirection` it is `IIS Url Rewrite`. I'd suggest as a starting point, you open Dev Tools in IE (F12) and in Chrome (Ctrl-Shift-I) and compare response headers.

Comment: I would recommend using Fiddler to see exactly what the request/response are.